# Differentiability Of Multivariable Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
x\sin(1/x) + y\sin(1/y), &xy \neq 0 \\
x \sin(1/x), &y=0, x \neq 0 \\
y \sin(1/y), &x=0, y\neq 0 \\
0, &x=y=0.
\end{cases}
$$
I have to check differentiability at origin , i have seen that partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ do not exist and so it is not differentiable at $(0,0)$. Am I right ? Else how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @GitGud THANKS.